# MySQL query to SUM results if php value is less then result

Tags: php, mysql, sum

Sorry in advance for a long post... 
I have this form where a user inputs a *startdate*, and a *enddate* the result will be sent to a PHP file that is making variables of the result like this:
**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['user_selected_dates'])) {
    $invoice_startdate = $_POST['start_date'];
    $invoice_enddate = $_POST['end_date'];
}
```

Then there is this nasty MySQL query...

```
SELECT

  s.student_socialnr, s.student_lastname, s.student_firstname,
  cs.city_name,
  c.customer_name,
  scp.cpl_startdate, scp.cpl_enddate, scp.cpl_coursename, scp.cpl_pricevalue,
  SUM(scpe.scpe_days) AS total_days, scp.cpl_pricevalue * SUM(scpe.scpe_days) AS      total_invoice

 FROM studentcourseplan scp
   INNER JOIN students s ON s.student_id = scp.student_id
   INNER JOIN studentcourseplanelements scpe ON scpe.scpe_cpl_id = scp.cpl_id
   INNER JOIN cityselections cs ON cs.city_id = s.student_city_id
   INNER JOIN customers c ON c.customer_id = s.student_customer_id
 WHERE scp.cpl_startdate BETWEEN '$invoice_startdate' AND '$invoice_enddate'

 GROUP BY scp.cpl_id ORDER BY s.student_lastname ASC
```

that will output something like this in a table (using a PHP `mysql_fetch_array`):

```
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+------------+---------------+
| student_socialnr | student_lastname | student_firstname | customer_name | cpl_startdate | cpl_enddate   | cpl_coursename | cpl_pricevalue | total_days | total_invoice |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+------------+---------------+
| 000000-0000      | Doe              | John              | A name        | 2012-06-01    | 2012-06-30    | A coursename   | 620            | 40         | 24800         |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+------------+---------------+
| 000000-0000      | Clerksson        | Lisa              | A name        | 2012-01-05    | 2012-07-30    | A coursename   | 950            | 10         | 9500          |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+------------+---------------+
| 000000-0000      | Derpson          | Derp              | A name        | 2012-04-01    | 2012-04-05    | A coursename   | 620            | 40         | 24800         |
+------------------+------------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+------------+---------------+
```

Now I'm looking for a function that will do the following: 
Create a value for the amount of days between `$invoice_startdate` and `$invoice_enddate`. 
If this value is **smaller** then the value of result in column `total_days` do a calculation:
 
 Column `price_value` * [the result of the new value] and output it to every row (but only if its smaller then the value from the database...)
Perhaps it could be done in the `MySQL`-query? 
I would really appriciate some help. This is my first website using PHP and MySQL so bear with me!
Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking at using a combination of the MySQL IF() and TO_DAYS() functions.  So something like this:

```
SELECT IF( TO_DAYS(DATE_DIFF('$invoice_enddate', '$invoice_startdate')) < total_days, price_value * ... ) as total_invoice
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining that a bit further? I think it's on the right direction but I am unsuccessful in putting it inside my query

Comment: I'm not sure what exact calculation you want done in each case, but it would be:

SELECT IF( TO_DAYS(DATE_DIFF('$invoice_enddate', '$invoice_startdate')) < total_days, (calculation for diff < total_days here), (calculation for diff > total_days here) ) as total_invoice ...

So it could be something like this:

Comment: Hmm, sorry I pressed enter too soon -- still new to StackOverflow.  :)  Anyway, here's what it should say:

I'm not sure what exact calculation you want done in each case, but it would be:

    SELECT IF( TO_DAYS(DATE_DIFF('$invoice_enddate', '$invoice_startdate')) < total_days, (calculation for diff < total_days here), (calculation for diff > total_days here) ) as total_invoice ...

I'm not exactly clear on what the calculations you're wanting to do in each case though -- could you give the SQL examples for both?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself by adding the following code to my query:

```
CASE WHEN SUM(scpe.scpe_days) > DATEDIFF('$invoice_enddate', '$invoice_startdate') THEN
 (scp.cpl_pricevalue * DATEDIFF('$invoice_enddate', '$invoice_startdate')) ELSE SUM(scpe.scpe_days) * scp.cpl_pricevalue
END AS to_invoice
```